# Problems with reading, overwriting and showing a txt file C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I got some problems with reading from a txt file. My proj. it's kind of a game, which is able to record highscores, show them and reset them aswell.
The problem is that if I reset the highscores (via a ToolStripMenuItem from the main form), the higscores form stops updating.

For example, a step-by-step approach:

> 1. open app (via debugger) (I mention that the .txt is clean)
> 2. play a game, record a highscore
> 3. see the highscores form, my highscore is there
> 4. reset the highscores
> 5. open the highscore form again, my highscore is still there. (but it is cleared from the .txt file, because if I reopen the game and open
>      de highscore form again, it is clean)

If I do the steps like 1-2-4-3, when i see the highscores form, it is clean.

Some codes:
The reset button works like this:

```
private void resetToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult reset = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to reset the highscores?", "Reset highscores", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (reset == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            File.WriteAllText("highscores.txt", string.Empty);
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully reset highscores");
        }
    }
```

The highscores form_load is like this:

```
 StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("highscores.txt");
        easy = 0; med = 0; hard = 0;
        while ((x = inputFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] words = x.Split('*');
            m = 0;
            foreach (string s in words)
            {
                // here comes some code which keeps one highscore in memory
            }
            // here is that one highscore sorted by difficulty
        }
        inputFile.Close();
//here are the highscores sorted
```

I didn't write all the code because it was too long, and I believe, irrelevant.
Here is the writing of highscores in the txt: (when completing the game, a new form appears with a textbox and a button, here is the code:)

```
if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            while (ok == 0)
            {
                string s = textBox1.Text;
                ok = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (s[i] == '*') ok = 0;
                }
                if (ok == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your name must not contain the '*' character");
                    textBox1.Text = "";

                }
            }

            StreamWriter outputFile = File.AppendText("highscores.txt");
            outputFile.WriteLine(Form1.dificultate + "*" + Form1.secunde.ToString() + "*" + Form1.moves + "*" + textBox1.Text);
            outputFile.Close();

        }
```

Comment: You can't expect to clear a high scores file and then show them, the real problem here seems to be is that once cleared, the "form" (I presume this means the textfile) won't store any new results.. is this correct? if so your problem lies within the writing of the `highscores.txt`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure where the problem lies, so I'm editing the post right now and I'll add the code of writing of the txt. Wait for it.

Comment: ...legendary. Sorry, I just couldn't resist.

Comment: When you reset high scores and reopen the window, is your high score deleted or is it still there?

Comment: @Flater Ha ha, that was nice timing.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov if I reset and then reopen the game, the highscores are deleted.

Comment: Its hard to see where your problem lies but I think the solution is to rethink how you use your highscores, you should load the text file when first starting your program into a list then use this list to populate your forms and modify your highscores, then when closing the application. you save this list back to your text file as required

Comment: @Sayse ok, thanks for your piece of advice. I'm gonna look for a lists tutorial since I'm not used to them.

Comment: Each time you open the high-score form, do you reuse the same form (just set visible/invisible), or do you create a new one each time? If you just set visible, your form won't load again, and it won't read from the txt file.

Comment: @Terje I believe that is the problem, but I don't really know how to fix it. The button that opens that form is like this: DialogResult dr7 = new DialogResult();
            dr7 = frm7.ShowDialog();
            frm7.high();. The high() is the one that loads from the txt, sorts and shows the highscores.

Comment: The code inside your for(;;) loop doesn't run when the file is empty.  So it won't reset the high scores either.

Comment: @HansPassant you're a genius. that was the problem and solved it and now it works. thanks. (I think you could post that as an answer so I can accept your answer or upvote or I don't know)

Comment: I can't really answer a question based on missing code.  Just post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hans Passant said, yhe problem was that the for(;;) loop didn't run while the txt was empty. (after it was reset).

```
while ((x = inputFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            c++;
          //reading and keeping in memory the highscores
        }
  if(c==0) //make all the highscore labels empty, skip sorting the highscores
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event `OnVisibleChanged` to the form, (Docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onvisiblechanged.aspx)), and inside that, load the high-score file.

To avoid reloading the high-score list everytime the highscore form is shown(if that is a problem), you can set a global flag when resetting the highscore list, and this flag can decide whether to reload the file again.

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it correctly, but here is the code which I wrote in the highscores form, and it doesn't work. protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            high();
        }

Comment: If you could tell me exactly where and what to write, that'd be great. P.S. The high() loads the txt file, sorts and shows the results in some labels on the highscore form.

Comment: That looks correct. Did you add the event? Form1.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(this.Form1_VisibleChanged);

Comment: where should I write that? (p.s. my highscores form is actually named Form7. Form1 is my main form)

Comment: Just right after you construct Form7() will be fine.